# SQL query to print occupation with print name with order

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Query an alphabetically ordered list of all names in OCCUPATIONS, immediately followed by the first letter of each profession as a parenthetical (i.e.: enclosed in parentheses).

For example:

```
AnActorName(A), ADoctorName(D), AProfessorName(P), and ASingerName(S)
```

Query the number of occurrences of each occupation in OCCUPATIONS. Sort the occurrences in ascending order, and output them in the following format:

```
SELECT name||'('||SUBSTR(occupation, 1, 1)||')'
FROM occupations
ORDER BY name

UNION

SELECT "There are a total of"|| count(*) from occupations group by occupation;
```

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Comment: please give sample input and output data

Comment: String constants need to be enclosed in **single** quotes in SQL, double quotes are for column or table names. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select concat(name, '(',left(occupation,1),')') 
from occupations 
order by name asc;

select 'There are a total of ' ,count(occupation) ,concat(lower(occupation), 's.') 
from occupations
group by occupation 
order by count(occupation) asc, occupation asc;
```

//[status of Testcase passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyaA4.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

My Approach

```
  select CONCAT(Name,'(',substr(OCCUPATION,1,1),')') 
    from OCCUPATIONS 
order by Name asc;

  select CONCAT('There are a total of ',count(OCCUPATION),' ',lower(OCCUPATION),'s.') 
    from OCCUPATIONs group by OCCUPATION 
order by COUNT(OCCUPATION) asc,OCCUPATION asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` has to be last clause when you use `UNION/UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT name||'('||SUBSTR(occupation, 1, 1)||')' AS col
FROM occupations
union
select 'There are a total of'|| count(*) 
from occupations 
group by occupation
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col LIKE 'There are a total%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, col;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, funny thing is that during copy paste from OP's core I changed it inside `WHERE` clause :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: see output]

sample input and output with code:

```
create table ns_occupations(name varchar(20));

insert into NS_OCCUPATIONS values('AActorName');

insert into NS_OCCUPATIONS values('ADoctorName');

insert into NS_OCCUPATIONS values('AProfessorName');

insert into NS_OCCUPATIONS values('ASingerName');


insert into NS_OCCUPATIONS values('ASingerName');

select * from NS_OCCUPATIONS;

SELECT name||'('||SUBSTR(name, 2, 1)||')'  shortname,count(*)  no_of_occupations
FROM ns_occupations
group by name||'('||SUBSTR(name, 2, 1)||')';

output:
ADoctorName(D)  1
AActorName(A)   1
AProfessorName(P)   1
ASingerName(S)  2
```

Answer (score 0):

select name+'('+left(occupation,1)+')' from occupations
order by name
union
select 'There are a total of '+convert(nvarchar,count(occupation))+' '+occupation+'s.' from occupations
group by occupation
order by count(occupation);

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query. If you don't use **UNION** then it will display the column name for the second table, which is not the ask.

```
FROM OCCUPATIONS
ORDER BY NAME)

UNION 

(SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ',COUNT(OCCUPATION),' ',LOWER(OCCUPATION),'s.')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY COUNT(OCCUPATION),OCCUPATION);
```